# Why does using ServiceStack JwtAuthProviderReader add auth endpoints to my resource API?

Tags: servicestack

I have set up an authentication server that issues JWT Tokens.

I now have setup my first resource service that will authenticate/authorize using the bearer token provided in a request. This service is not my auth server, it is a resource server.

I added the ServiceStack `JwtAuthProviderReader` to my resource service:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
new IAuthProvider[] {
    new JwtAuthProviderReader() {
        HashAlgorithm = "HS256",
        AuthKeyBase64 = AuthSettings.JwtAuthKeyBase64
    },
}));
```

Why does my resource server now have all the auth server endpoints, I am using the `JwtAuthProviderReader`, not the `JwtAuthProvider` that my auth service does. [As the documentation states](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#services-only-validating-tokens), my resource service is only validating tokens.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These aren't limited to just the JWT AuthProvider, they're ServiceStack's built-in Auth Services for handling any ServiceStack Authentication, i.e. when registering the ServiceStack's `AuthFeature` plugin.

If you're not using Assign/Unassign Roles Services, they can be disabled with:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(...) {
    IncludeAssignRoleServices = false
});
```

You can also hide Services from showing up in the metadata pages and Services by [dynamically adding Exclude attributes](http://docs.servicestack.net/routing#dynamically-adding-route-attributes) in the AppHost's **constructor**, e.g:

```
public AppHost() : base("MyApp", typeof(MyServices).Assembly)
{
    typeof(Authenticate)
        .AddAttributes(new ExcludeAttribute(Feature.Metadata));
}
```

Which is equivalent to adding the attribute on the Request DTO, e.g:

```
[Exclude(Feature.Metadata)]
public class Authenticate { ... }
```